# General term of the sequence and series for the following

Tags: sequences-and-series

Whats is the general term of the sequence for each value of $n$ corresponding to the value of $f(n)$?
$ n = 2,\;3,\;4,\;5,\;6,\;7,\;8,\;9,\;10,\;11,\;12,\;13,\;14,\;15,\;16,\;17,\;18,\;19,\;20,\;21,\;22,\;23,\;24,\;25,\;26,\;27,\;28,\;29,\;30,\;31,\;32,\;33,\;34,... $\
$f(n)= 2,\;2,\;2,\;2,\;3,\;3,\;4,\;4,\;4,\;4,\;4,\;5,\;5,\;6,\;6,\;6,\;6,\;6,\;7,\;7,\;8,\;8,\;8,\;8,\;8,\;9,\;9,\;10,\;10,\;10,\;10,\;10,\;11,...$.

Comment: There is no corresponding series like this in the OEIS. It will be much clearer if you could tell the concept that led you to such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

$$f(n)= \begin{cases} 2\lceil \frac{n}{7}\rceil+1& \text{if } rem(n,7) \in \{0, 6\} \\ 2\lceil \frac{n}{7}\rceil& \text{otherwise } \end{cases}$$

where $rem(n,7)$ denotes the remainder when $n$ is divided by $7$.